# Using scope in Facebook login official example

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I know some Facebook users doesn't have email address. They can use phone number. Anyway, I can't figure out in which part of code I should add `{scope: 'email'}` in this official JS example.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I figured out. Solution is to add `email` param here

```
function testAPI() {
console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response) {  //<-HERE ?fields=name,email
  console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
    'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + response.id + response.email +'!';
});
```

}

Comment: you actually asked where to add the scope parameter, not where to ask for the email field in an api call...i will add that to my answer too, in a better way though. check it out, the second parameter it is.

Answer (score 1):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

It´s right there in the docs, just scroll down a bit.

...or with an arrow function:

```
FB.login((response) => {
  // handle the response
}, {scope: 'email'});
```

After authorization, you can get the email with this API call:

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email'}, (response) => {
    console.log(response.email);
});
```